# Sorting columns with timestamps into sessions

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with a data set that records user activity on a web course. We have about 50 thousand users and 20 million events in total. We are running postgres 9.5.

The `events` table includes a `created_at` (timestamp) and `user_id` column. I want to add a `time` column to this table which stores, in seconds, the estimated amount of time between subsequent events for each user. I also want to separate `events` into user sessions, which are delimited by periods of >30 minutes with no activity. Ideally, these sessions would count up from 1 for each user, but I can live with a global sequence.

With the following window query, I'm solving the first part of the problem -- estimating time between events. I set the seconds to NULL when it's greater than 30 minutes to represent the end of a session.

```
SELECT user_id, id, date_part AS diff,
    CASE WHEN date_part > 1800 THEN NULL ELSE date_part END AS seconds 
FROM 
    (SELECT user_id, id, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (lead - time)) 
    FROM 
    (SELECT user_id, id, created_at AS time, lead(created_at) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) 
        FROM events) AS A) AS B;
```

This leaves me with the following result:

```
         user_id |   id    |      diff       |   seconds   
-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------
               1 |    1934 |        4.499914 |    4.499914
               1 |    1935 |        3.275266 |    3.275266
               1 |    1936 |   125676.773213 |            
               1 |    2994 |        3.064404 |    3.064404
               1 |    2995 |        4.692644 |    4.692644
               1 |    3134 |        9.889537 |    9.889537
               1 |    2996 |       32.071339 |   32.071339
               1 |    2924 |       28.536395 |   28.536395
               1 |    2997 |       1.508108  |   
               2 |    3236 |       18.364849 |   18.364849
               2 |    3243 |       12.052791 |   12.052791
               2 |    3245 |    12936.064333 |            
               2 |    3621 |        8.559128 |    8.559128
               2 |    3672 |      381.158063 |  381.158063
               2 |    3673 | 10797574.575174 |            
               2 | 1264501 |        3.242143 |    3.242143
               2 | 1264546 |     1135.754492 | 1135.754492
               2 | 1264577 |      256.417076 |  256.417076
               2 | 1264244 | 18137835.531789 |            
               2 | 2736714 |       43.244278 |   43.244278
               2 | 2736781 |    36204.912999 |            
               2 | 2747358 |        2.962074 |    2.962074
               2 | 2747359 |     39448.37133 |
```

How can I modify this query to add a `session` column where the first three events in the example (up to and including the NULL seconds value) are session 1, and the rest are session 2? Right now my best solution is looping through users and events in ruby, which takes too long.

```
         user_id |   id    |      diff       |   seconds   |    session
-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------
               1 |    1934 |        4.499914 |    4.499914 |        1
               1 |    1935 |        3.275266 |    3.275266 |        1
               1 |    1936 |   125676.773213 |             |        1
               1 |    2994 |        3.064404 |    3.064404 |        2
               1 |    2995 |        4.692644 |    4.692644 |        2
               1 |    3134 |        9.889537 |    9.889537 |        2
               1 |    2996 |       32.071339 |   32.071339 |        2
               1 |    2924 |       28.536395 |   28.536395 |        2
               1 |    2997 |        1.508108 |             |        2
               2 |    3236 |       18.364849 |   18.364849 |        3
               2 |    3243 |       12.052791 |   12.052791 |        3
               2 |    3245 |    12936.064333 |             |        3
               2 |    3621 |        8.559128 |    8.559128 |        4
               2 |    3672 |      381.158063 |  381.158063 |        4
               2 |    3673 | 10797574.575174 |             |        4
               2 | 1264501 |        3.242143 |    3.242143 |        5
               2 | 1264546 |     1135.754492 | 1135.754492 |        5
               2 | 1264577 |      256.417076 |  256.417076 |        5
               2 | 1264244 | 18137835.531789 |             |        5
               2 | 2736714 |       43.244278 |   43.244278 |        6
               2 | 2736781 |    36204.912999 |             |        6
               2 | 2747358 |        2.962074 |    2.962074 |        7
               2 | 2747359 |     39448.37133 |             |        7
```

Thanks!

Comment: please include your desire output

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza done.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ROW_NUMBER()` validate the `ORDER BY` if you can use a field better, but i think you can use `NULL`

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT user_id, 
           id, 
           date_part AS diff,
           CASE  
                WHEN date_part > 1800 THEN NULL 
                ELSE date_part 
           END AS seconds,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ()) rn
    FROM 
        (SELECT user_id, id, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (lead - time)) 
         FROM 
             (SELECT user_id, 
                     id, 
                     created_at AS time, 
                     lead(created_at) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) 
              FROM events) AS A
            ) AS B
)
SELECT *, CASE WHEN rn <= 3 THEN 1 
               ELSE 2
          END as session              
FROM cte
```

Comment: Umm....not sure I understand. That of course works on the sample output I provided, but it's not particularly useful for solving the general problem. I have 30 million rows, not 8.

Comment: You request was, 3 first row will be session 1, other will be session 2... So what is the difference if more rows? Be more precise in your question

Comment: That's the example of what should happen if the correct query is applied to that particular example. I don't want to literally add 1 to the first 3 columns and 2 to the rest.

In the general case, I want to iterate through those events and assign a session number to events. For a particular user, 'sessions' are separated by a NULL seconds value, which indicates that they had no activity for over 30 minutes. So if they did 5 things, then came back the next day and did 40 things, then later did 10 things, those groups would have session numbers of 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

Comment: I added more events to the example. Hopefully that clarifies the question.

Comment: I dont have time to try understand your question. Here is should how work. You already provide output and desire, but you didnt provide the Source Data so I cant test it. You need provide all three. And you can provide a fiddle like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18993. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.